# Why does contains value return false?

Tags: java, collections, treemap

Please don't mind the my convention mistakes

```
class test implements Comparable<test>
{
    int id;
    String name;
    public test(int id,String name)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(test o) {
        if(this.id>o.id)
            return 1;
        else if(this.id==o.id)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;

    }
}
class le
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<test,test> p=new TreeMap<test,test>();
        p.put(new test(1,"sad"), new test(3121, "adweq"));
        p.put(new test(2, "asds"),new test(3123,"awdq"));
        p.put(new test(23,"akjdb"),new test(23123,"dqWQDD"));
        Set<Map.Entry<test,test>> s=p.entrySet();
        Iterator <Map.Entry<test, test>> i=s.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<test, test> m=i.next();
            System.out.println(m.getKey().id);
            System.out.println(m.getValue().name);
        }
        System.out.println(p.containsKey(new test(1,"sad")));//returning true
        System.out.println(p.containsValue(new test(3123,"awdq")));//why it is returning false
    }   
}
```

here i have made a treemap,and wanted to know why does in containsvalue method it return false? whereas i have implemented comparable interface>

Comment: Values are compared using `equals`, not `compareTo`.

Comment: The API documentation tells us that the equals() method is used to compare the values. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Because `containsValue` relies on `.equals`, not `.compareTo`, and you haven't provided an override for equals, so it defaults to the referential equality that `Object#equals(Object)` provides by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `compareTo()` method is not enough - you need to implement an `equals()` method (and is recommended to also override `hashCode()` when you override `equals()`). Here's how:

```
class test implements Comparable<test>
{
    int id;
    String name;
    public test(int id,String name)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(test o) {
        if(this.id>o.id)
            return 1;
        else if(this.id==o.id)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o == null) 
        return false;
      if(!this.getClass().equals(o.getClass()) 
        return false;

      test that = (test) o;
      return this.compareTo(that) == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return id; }
}
```

**Side note**
Why does equals() use `getClass().equals(o.getClass())` rather than `(o instanceof test)`?

Let us assume there is a subclass of the test class called test2 and that t1 and t2 are objects of type test, test2 (respectively).

If test2 overrides equals() then `t1.equals(t2)` can yield different result than `t2.equals(t1)` if `equals()` in test were implemented using `instanceof`. This violates the `equals()` contract (specifically, the symmetric requirement).

Comment: Why not `if (!o instanceof test) return false;`? Seems like a long-winded way of doing it. That handles both `null` and non-`test` objects in one check.

Comment: @JonK: Added a short explanation inside the answer.

Comment: Generally I would expect two objects of different classes not to be equal. The situation you're describing only happens if someone implements an equals method that *allows* an object of a different class to be equal, which I would argue is poor design. It would be surprising behaviour to say the least.

Comment: @JonK: Exactly my point: `if (!o instanceof test) return false` will *not* return with a false when `o` is a subclass of test.

Comment: Ah - now I see where you're coming from. Thanks for clearing that up, although you may want to edit that into your answer as it's a little confusingly worded at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Because your class `test` doesn't override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, something like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof test) {
    test t = (test) o;
    return t.id == o.id;
  }
  return false;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return Integer.valueOf(id).hashCode();
}
```

Assuming that id equality is sufficient. Additionally, `test` is a poor class name. The Java naming convention would be `Test` but that's also a poor name. Maybe, `EqualityTest` (so it has some meaning).

Comment: i was in a hurry to go through my topics,that's why i wrote it in the first line,sorry for the conventions ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `Object.equals` in your `Test` class in order to check for equality between `new test(3123,"awdq")` and another instance of `new test(3123,"awdq")`.

It is also recommended to override `Object.hashCode` when overriding `equals`.